# How to reduce space between x-axis origin and y-axis origin in seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

Can anyone tell me how to reduce space between x origin and y origin ,

kindly check out the image link , as im new to stack over flow , i dont have points to paste the image directly

```
sns.distplot(titanic['fare'],bins=30,kde=False,color='red')
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the x-axis left limit accordingly. For example, you can choose 0, or -5, -2, etc whichever gives you a desired figure

```
ax = sns.distplot(titanic['fare'],bins=30,kde=False,color='red')
ax.set_xlim(-2, None) # you can replace -2 with a value of your choice
```

Comment: Thank you , it worked :)

Comment: My reputation is low , although i click on grey up mark ,nothing has changed  . Thanks :)